# C# Windows Service doesn't run

Tags: c#, windows, service

I wrote my first C# Windows Service:
Now I have a little Issue. If I Debug the code like that

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        m_thread = new Thread(execute);
        m_thread.Start();
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

The Code works quite well.

But If I install and run the Service, nothing happens.
I start the service with the OnStart method (See below)

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    m_thread = new Thread(execute);
    m_thread.IsBackground = true;
    m_thread.Start();
    base.OnStart(args);
}
```

The execute method will create some sub tasks like enter a Value in a DB

```
public static void execute()
{
    var cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationToken token = cancellationSource.Token;
    Console.WriteLine("RUN");
    var t1 = Task.Run(() => WriteData("test", "test", token));
}
```

As I said in the beginning of this post, When I ran this in "Debug Mode" everything works, and the values are entered in the DB. But if I install & run it, the values will not be entered in the DB.

Can anyone explain me why or what I forgot?

Comment: Why do you use a `Task` in a `Thread` that is running in the background?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, which made my life easier when dealing with windows services; take a look at topshelf. You can use a console app approach and easily install it as a service. http://topshelf-project.com/

Comment: Best way to find out what's happening is to debug the service. This can usually be quite hard since your code is probably already done by the time you manage to find it in "Attach to Process". Two easy methods to get around that problem are: 1. Add a `Thread.Sleep(15000)` at the start of your code and try "Attach top Process", or 2. use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` to force the service to attach to a debugger (this usually launches a new VS instance or you can select an opened one). I usually use the second option in combination with a startup argument - works like a charm.

Comment: Uh... well if you are not interactive, you do nothing. There is **nothing** in your `else` block. What exactly did you expect that nothing would do?

Comment: @nvoigt From the looks of it, that part is not included in the service implementation.

Comment: Have you tried removing `m_thread.IsBackground = true;`?

Comment: The else-clause should not be empty, ServiceBase.Run() required.  Look at the auto-generated code in Program.cs produced by the Windows Service project template.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happened to your project, but services don't get started by the magic service fairy. You actually have to *do* that. At some point in time, your `Main` method looked like this:

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService(args) };
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

That code got lost. Put it back, preferably in your empty `else` block.

Comment: I Added this to main main function, but it doesn't do anything

Comment: @StefanRöthlisberger Please post your full code, preferably a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered when creating my own services, was that the Main thread does not get blocked when ran as a service or as User Interactive.
If the main thread exits- then it terminates the application.
Remember - it is still a console application - if the Main thread (static void main() ) exits - then the application effectively reaches the end of its life.

I solved it easily by adding a Console.ReadLine(); to prevent the application ever reaching the end of the Start method.

Alternatives include looping - and then using the Stop method to provide a means to break out of the infinite loop.

Comment: I also added Console.readline(); at the end of the OnStart method, but it doesn't solve my problem